# Difference between して and させて

Tags: grammar, causation

I know the basic difference between して　and させて。

however in the following examples, I am getting a little confused.

アプリを起動して。

アプリを起動させて。

車を発進して。

車を発進させて。

How exactly are they different?

Comment: This depends on the suru-verb. I feel 起動する is almost completely bitransitive, so アプリを起動する and アプリを起動させる feel exactly the same to me. For 発進, I tend to take it as intransitive, so I personally prefer 車を発進させる.

Answer (score -2):

車を発進して and アプリを起動して are subjective (主観的)

アプリを起動させて and 車を発進させて are objective (客観的)

〜させる、は使役（しえき）という表現で、何かを使ってそれがされることです